# find out the culprit process

Tags: linux, monitoring

This is rather a basic linux administration question. We have a CentOS linux machine running a production application. There are 10 application specific processes running on that machine. `Once in every 3/4 days, the linux machine freezes` and the only way to get it back is to hard reboot it from Amazon AWS console.

We have Amazon Cloudwatch enabled which captures the CPU usage every 5 minutes. We see that the CPU reaches 100% (8 cores) within in 10-15 seconds just before it freezes. And unfortunately we could not figure out anything from the process log files.

How do we really pin point `which process out of those 10 processes is causing the linux server to freeze?`

Are there any simple CPU/memory monitoring applications that can record the top cpu/memory hoggers to disk, say every 2 seconds? Appreciate any other ideas to figure out the culprit process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply run `top` in batch mode and save the output to a file:

```
$ top -b -d 2 > /your/log/file &
```

`-d 2` is the sampling period. Be warned that this will generate quite a bit of data.

You might want to use the `-u` option to only list processes for a given user, or even the `-p` option to explicitly list your application's processes.

Answer (score 0):

This link contains several (20) tools for monitoring processes. `top` of course is the most popular, but other tools such as `iotop` are useful too. `iotop` will show which processes are using the most file system IO.

http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/